# XlsxWriter write_formula() not working always show Zero (0)

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, python-3.5

I have work with xlsxwriter and I try to  print simple formula with a print of formula into the sheet

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename1.xlsx')
format_val=workbook.add_format()
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0,1,5)
worksheet.write(1,1,2)
worksheet.write_formula(3,0, '=SUM(B1:B2)')
workbook.close()
csvf = StringIO(import_file.read().decode())
```

[Here the Image of how to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOVwt.png) and when I press **=** than output is print **7**

But output also will be Zero (0). I know that XlsxWriter doesn’t calculate the result of a formula and instead stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be recalculated when the file is opened.

I have tried this. It is working for me but it's not a proper thing when I try with Upper Case is not working: ~

```
num_formate=format_val.set_num_format('0')
worksheet.write_formula(5,1, '=2+1',num_formate,4)
```

But when it's open How to show calculate value?

Comment: i think i know. try open output file by LibreOffice. if it will works, the problem is in that your office not support English. install English

Comment: What program are you using to view the output file? Excel, OpenOffice, etc.?

Comment: I will open the file in LibreOffice  but not value is set

Comment: What happens when you open it in Excel?

Comment: If you don't have constraints regarding com component then you can use win32.com api. by it you can use all the functions of excel vba. http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/

Comment: @jmcnamara When I Open the File The Formula is written Perfect but sum of the Formula is print zero (0) when I click the accept then value is print example :~=2+1 -> 0 after click accept in print 3.

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my machine. It must be some kind of setup that you have on your Excel.

Comment: @zipa I add the Image in my question what is actually show

Comment: Looks like it is an OpenOffice issue, since as other commenters are pointing out, it works in Excel. Maybe there is an OpenOffice setting that forces recalculation or maybe it is something that is fixed in a more recent version.

Comment: @jmcnamara ok I will try to something other devices..

Answer (score 1):

If you use `pandas.ExcelWriter` with `'xlsxwriter'` engine, and `.save()` it, then it the formula is as you expected. For your case:

```
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('filename1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook  = writer.book
format_val=workbook.add_format()
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0,1,5)
worksheet.write(1,1,2)
worksheet.write_formula(3,0, '=SUM(B1:B2)')
writer.save()
```

However, this write formula in the forth row and first column (A4). If you need to be in the third row and second column (B3), you should use:

```
worksheet.write_formula(2,1, '=SUM(B1:B2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing empty string to value arg works for me.

```py
# # xlsxwriter/worksheet.py
#
# class Worksheet(xmlwriter.XMLwriter):
# ...
#     def write_formula(self, row, col, formula, cell_format=None, value=0)

worksheet.write_formula(3, 0, '=SUM(B1:B2)', None, '')
```